# Sorting a dataframe by a column name passed to a function

Tags: r

I would like to write a function that sorts by a column. This elementary exercise has of course been asked many times before, but the solutions suggested either [depend on the literal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1296745/9295807) and hence cannot be used in a function (also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6871968/9295807), [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10758086/9295807), and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13156498/9295807)), or require [dependence on the column ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21971836/9295807), which makes for brittle programming (also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32883666/9295807)).

What I'm looking for has apparently been dubbed "referential transparency". Fine. But it appears that adopting this term, at least in the present example, would lead to [using very many words](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) to define and distinguish literals in a program. Hence an MWE is best.

What should the body of the function `sort.by.column` contain, so that

```
sort.by.column <- function(df, column.name) {
    ## ??
}

df1 <- data.frame(Instrument=c("B","A"),
                  Value=c(3,2))
df2 <- data.frame(Device=c("D","C"),
                  Value=c(5,4))
column.name.1 <- "Instrument"
sorted1 <- sort.by.column(df1, column.name.1)
column.name.2 <- "Device"
sorted2 <- sort.by.column(df2, column.name.2)
```

will work for both `df1` and `df2`?

Comment: what is wrong with using `dplyr::arrange`?  i.e. `sorted1 <- arrange(df1, Instrument)` - note that no quotes are required.  (if you do need the quotes, use `arrange_(df1, column.name.1)`)

Comment: @MelissaKey I too thought that `arrange_` will do the trick nicely, until I read that `arrange_` is deprecated. It seems weird to deprecate the more general of the (`arrange`/`arrange_`) pair, and so I'm asking to figure out the logic of it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the function `sort.by.column` using `order` as:

```
sort.by.column <- function(df, column.name) {
  df[order(df[,column.name]),]
}    

#Lets test the function

sort.by.column(df1, "Value")
#   Instrument Value
# 2          B     2
# 1          A     3
sort.by.column(df2, "Value")
#   Device Value
# 2      D     4
# 1      C     5

sort.by.column(df1, "Instrument")
#   Instrument Value
# 1          A     3
# 2          B     2
sort.by.column(df2, "Device")
#   Device Value
# 1      C     5
# 2      D     4
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- data.frame(Instrument=c("A","B"),
                  Value=c(3,2))
df2 <- data.frame(Device=c("C","D"),
                  Value=c(5,4))
```

**Explanation**

It works like this. With the initialization

```
df <- data.frame(Instrument=c("B","A"), Value=c(3,2))
col.name <- "Instrument"
```

the expression

```
df[,col.name]
```

returns a 1-column subset of the data frame. The expression

```
order(df[,col.name])
```

sorts that subset, returning the indices of the rows. Finally

```
df[order(df[,col.name]),]
```

returns a row-subset of the dataframe, with the row indices in the order computed.

Comment: Can you confirm that the explanation that I just appended to your answer is accurate, or provide one?

Comment: @Vrokipal Your description of the answer is appropriate. I have approved the your edit as well. Moreover, I dont suggest using any `library` for this function as result can be achieved using base=R.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a wrapper for  `dplyr::arrange` to take text:

```
library(dplyr)
sort.by.column <- function(df, column.name) {
  col <- sym(column.name)
  arrange(df, !!col)
}
```

Comment: I see that it works, but I'd like to know why. The double negation is clear enough, but what is the significance of treating a symbol, the result of the `sym` function, as a Boolean?

Comment: Actually, the `!!` is not being used as a double negation.  See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html for a good introduction on this.  The `rlang` package (which is imported into `dplyr`) is the replacement for `arrange_` and other such variants.

Answer (score 0):

I'm collecting here the solutions to confirm, compare, and understand.

```
s1 <- function(df, column.name) {
    #library(dplyr)    
    dplyr::arrange_(df, column.name)
}


# version which does not require a `library(dplyr)` call
a50915367 <- function(df, column.name) {
    # library(dplyr)
    col <- rlang::sym(column.name) # dplyr::sym also works
    dplyr::arrange(df, rlang::`!!`(col))    
}

library(dplyr) # required before function
a50915367 <- function(df, column.name) {
    col <- sym(column.name) 
    arrange(df, !!col)    
}

a50915313 <- function(df, column.name) {
    df[order(df[,column.name]),]
}

f <- function(sorting.function) {
    df1 <- data.frame(Instrument=c("B","A"), Value=c(3,2))
    df2 <- data.frame(Device=c("D","C"), Value=c(5,4))

    column.name.1 <- "Instrument"
    sorted1 <- sorting.function(df1, column.name.1)
    column.name.2 <- "Device"
    sorted2 <- sorting.function(df2, column.name.2)

    ret.list <- list(r1=sorted1,
                     r2=sorted2)
    ret.list
}

g <- function() {
    cat("----------------1----------------\n")
    print(f(s1))
    cat("----------------a50915367----------------\n")
    print(f(a50915367))
    cat("----------------a50915313----------------\n")
    print(f(a50915313))
}

g()
```

Comment: calling a library inside a function is usually bad practice.  I've edited your code to reflect how to call these functions without calling `library` first.